# cPanel file manager directory tree is not visible

Tags: centos, file-manager, vps

I am using VPS hosting and I am quite new to it. If you look at the attached image, you will clearly understand the problem. [Click here to see screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0xTwX.png)

I am going to explain too - My VPS is set up with cent OS 6. At the very first I can see the folder tree but since I an new to VPS, I explore about it on internet and try some commands. Later, I notice that when I go into file manager from cPanel, I can't see folder tree anymore.

What I tried!

1. I tried to change folder permissions
2. I have acquired root access with my user account

But nothing can fix the problem. Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For someone who might encounter this problem and come to this page. I tried to update cPanel to latest version as well but it didn't fix in my case. It was a permission problem and I run the bash code shared on [this website](http://thecpaneladmin.com/fix-account-permissions/)

1. I downloaded the [bash file she uploaded](http://thecpaneladmin.com/files/fixperms.sh.txt) by using **wget**
2. Rename the file to remove .txt at the end by using **mv**
3. And then I used sudo ./path/to/file.sh anoteruser

It would took some times to fix the permissions for each folder depending on the total number of files and folders on your server.